# Shell32.dll Reference Causing Problems

Tags: c#, unzip, windows-shell, codedom

I am making an application in C# with the .NET Framework of 3.5 with a feature that unzips a file; however, when I run it, as soon as it gets to the unzipping method it crashes with a Windows "stopped working" error. It does not read any lines within the method, just crashes upon entering it.

```
Description:
Stopped working

Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   test.exe
Problem Signature 02:   0.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   50b03509
Problem Signature 04:   Test
Problem Signature 05:   0.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   50b03509
Problem Signature 07:   1
Problem Signature 08:   38
Problem Signature 09:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
```

After using the debug feature from the "Stopped working menu" I get this error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Shell32, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I import the Shell32.dll within the CodeDom compiler using this code.

```
Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Interop.Shell32.dll");
```

Here is the code that unzips the file within the method that crashes.

```
Shell32.ShellClass sc = new Shell32.ShellClass();
                Shell32.Folder SrcFlder = sc.NameSpace(source);
                Shell32.Folder DestFlder = sc.NameSpace(dest);
                Shell32.FolderItems items = SrcFlder.Items();
                DestFlder.CopyHere(items, 20);
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. It works perfectly within the original application, but when I compile it using CodeDom (Produces no errors) and run it this occurs. Am I not referencing the COM properly?

Comment: `Could not load file or assembly ` - when you run [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and capture a HDD activity trace when the problem occurs, can you see where it is looking to load the DLL? and run a trace with the original application and let us know the differences.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have ProcMan, but I can't seem to figure out how to capture a HDD activity trace. If you don't mind, could you explain? Thanks.

Comment: @Hexo scroll down the page: http://forum.appointmentsbook.com/showthread.php?t=125

Comment: Nevermind, but the compiled one looks towards "C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll" while the actual looks towards "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll".

Comment: So when you target the x86 and compile does that set the Shell32  reference to the 32 bit system file path?

Comment: Yes. However, I stopped using the Windows Shell and am now using DotNetZip instead. Unfortunately, it requires the Ionic.Zip.dll and I can't seem to figure out how to embed it into the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Shell32, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

The reference has been loaded into your assembly. But your application can't find your COM dependency.

You need to have the 'Interop.Shell32.dll' on the root of your main executable.

For do it, on the Visual Studio we have an option when click on the reference, is the 'Copy Local' - Only set it to true, and the dependency will be copied to the application folder on the next build.

Then you can run your application with the library file present on the build folder.

Comment: I've done this and I put the compiled file inside the debug folder which contains the "Interop.Shell32.dll" file. However it still gives the same error.